# Extract only JSON from string in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a requirement in c# to extract the below JSON error message and read the title element.
I need to remove all the characters in the string and I want only starting from **errors**
i.e

```
{   
"errors": 
         [{       
            "status": "404",       
            "title":  "Not found data",
            "detail": "This is a sample line of error detail."     
         }] 
}
```

Please note that the exception can be anything so I just require to extract the JSON message starting from"errors".

Can you please assist me?

Code

```
string sb="{465F6CE7-3DF9-4BAF-8DD0-3E116CDAC9E7}0xc0c0167a0System.Net.WebException: There was no endpoint listening at http://TestData/member that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
{   "errors": [     {       "status": "404",       "title":  "Not found data","detail": "This is a sample line of error detail."     }   ] }";
```

Comment: In the example there are a newline followed by a `{`.... You could `sb.IndexOf("\r\n{")` or `sb.IndexOf("{")` to find the beggining of the json.

Comment: `sb.Substring(sb.IndexOf("{", 1)))` - for the case posted above it will work, it obviously depends on what type of messages you'll be working with, the information you provided is not enough for a general purpose solution so you'll need to tweak it. This will skip the first character and look for the first occurence of `{` and take everything from that point to the end.

Comment: I'm using a regex after the Errors -I'm able to extract from '[' till ']'  var regexp = new Regex("([[].+[]])"); So I believe it's ok for me to extract from this part and I will use the Indexof to select the Title value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to extract a specific sequence of text from a random string of text, this sounds like a regular expression.

The lazy mans solution: 
If you're just looking to read the title, you could just do IndexOf on "title", and then read to the next quotation mark that's not preceded by a backward-slash.

Comment: I'm using a regex after the Errors -I'm able to extract from '[' till ']'  var regexp = new Regex("([[].+[]])") var matchstring= regex.match(sb); So I believe it's ok for to extract from this part and I will use the Indexof to select the Title value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var pattern = @"\{(\s?)\'errors.*";
    string sb = "{465F6CE7-3DF9-4BAF-8DD0-3E116CDAC9E7}0xc0c0167a0System.Net.WebException: There was no endpoint listening at http://TestData/member that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. { 'errors': [ { 'status': '404', 'title': 'Not found data','detail': 'This is a sample line of error detail.' } ] }";
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(sb, pattern);
```

I have changed the " to ', so just change the pattern to match ".

`matches` is not an array of all matches `matches[0]` will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.NET. So, you need to parse your string into `JObject` i.e.

```
string sb = @"{   ""errors"": [     {       ""status"": ""404"",       ""title"":  ""Not found data"",""detail"": ""This is a sample line of error detail.""     }   ] }";

JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(sb);
JArray errors = (JArray)jsonObject["errors"];

foreach(var item in errors.Children())
{
     int itemStatus = (int)item["status"];
     string itemTitle = (string)item["title"];
     string itemDetail = (string)item["detail"];
}
```

So, in this loop you can get what you want i have shown all the elements from the JSON that can be extracted.

Hope this helps you :)